# Firebase CORS - Unhandled error typeError: Cannot read property origin of undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform

Currently trying to fun a google cloud function directly from my webapp which makes a mongodb query and returns the data to the clients browser. And I get the following error.

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-fullName"
>  {"verifications":{"app":"MISSING","auth":"MISSING"},"logging.googleapis.com/labels":{"firebase-log-type":"callable-request-verification"},"severity":"INFO","message":"Callable request verification passed"}
>  {"severity":"ERROR","message":"Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined\n    at C:\\Users\\myalt\\s\\functions\\node_modules\\cors\\lib\\index.js:219:40\n    at optionsCallback (C:\\Users\\myalt\\s\\functions\\node_modules\\cors\\lib\\index.js:199:9)\n    at corsMiddleware (C:\\Users\\myalt\\s\\functions\\node_modules\\cors\\lib\\index.js:204:7)\n    at C:\\Users\\myalt\\s\\functions\\index.js:6:5\n    at newHandler (C:\\Users\\myalt\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\emulator\\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:296:16)\n    at C:\\Users\\myalt\\s\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\common\\providers\\https.js:322:32\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)"}
i  functions: Finished "us-central1-fullName" in ~1s
```

I was originally receiving this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1--8955f.cloudfunctions.net/fullName' from origin 'https://-8955f.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

However, I fixed this by adding

```
const cors = require('cors')({ Origin: true });
```

```
exports.fullName = functions.region('us-central1').https.onCall((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
// my function
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why this origin error is happening. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
const cors = require('cors')({ Origin: true });

exports.fullName = functions.region('us-central1').https.onCall((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { //  return a promise, so Cloud Functions knows to wait
            var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
            var url = "mongodb://:/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false";
            MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
                console.log('Connected to database.')
                if (err) throw err;
                var dbo = db.db("discord_pandemic");
                dbo.collection("ArrayStats").find().toArray(function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    const totalInfections = result[0].total_infections
                    const totalUsers = result[0].total_users
                    const totalCommands = result[0].total_commands
                    const totalLiveInfections = result[0].total_live_infections
                    const totalLiveInfectedChannels = result[0].total_live_infected_channels
                    const data = {
                        totalInfections: totalInfections,
                        totalUsers: totalUsers,
                        totalCommands: totalCommands,
                        totalLiveInfections: totalLiveInfections,
                        totalLiveInfectedChannels: totalLiveInfectedChannels
                    }
                    resolve(data); //  resolve the promise with the data for the user
                });
            });
        });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages: “TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined” indicates that within your code you are calling the property: code/status, while this property is being NULL. This could be a callback confusion such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290857/getting-typeerror-cannot-read-property-catch-of-undefined-when-executing-a?rq=1) where it is mentioned that is because send is probably not returning a promise, it uses the callback method instead. On the other hand, this could be just missing a definition just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848105/google-drive-api-cannot-read-property-oauth2-of-undefined/49848309#49848309) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60748905/cannot-read-property-installed-of-undefined-express-js). Not sure if you have checked the shared links before, but if not, I would recommend you to check them.